# Is it possible to pass the google api client object to a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, google-api, google-classroom

I have got the following authentication function:

```
course_id = "Classexample"
def connect():
    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    return service
```

and the following Google Classroom function

```
def teachers_list(course_Id, service):
    lst1 = service.courses().teachers().list(courseId=course_Id).execute()
    lst1 = lst1.get('teachers', [])
    teachers = {}
    for T in lst1:
        teachers[T["userId"]] = T['profile']['emailAddress']

    return teachers
```

Running it like

```
print(teachers_list(course_id, connect()))
```

Whenever I run this, I get error 401, that I don't have the authentication credential. The problem with this is that I do, and in the case of the program written in only one function, it somehow works. I might end up combining all functions even if it's messy but I would like to know why this is happening anyway.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] showing how you're calling the functions.

Comment: @Barmar Added the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in your assumption and your code appears to be fine (and you should try to not mash everything into a single function).

Given your statement, that it works as a single function, I suspect (!?) that what you're presenting as the code in your question is incorrect.

When you say "Running it like", is the `print` statement part of the process, i.e.:

```py
course_id = ...

def connect():
    ...

def teachers_list(course_id, service):
    ...


print(teachers_list(course_id, connect()))
```

Or perhaps as part of `main`:

```py
course_id = ...

def connect():
    ...

def teachers_list(course_id, service):
    ...

def main():
    print(teachers_list(course_id, connect()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Both of these configurations will (!) work.